# No xorg.conf, is framebufferCompression to off, possible without?

Tags: xorg

Debian Sid with no xorg.conf.
Tried to make it with tutorial which contained two techniques:

```
sudo su -

Xorg -confugure
```

OR single user!

No go errors upon errors... Don't want to go there if not necessary.

Well let's say I don't want that xorg.conf but still need to get

`framebufferCompression off`

Is it possible to pass this feature without xorg.conf?